# cssh intercepts F10

Tags: escape-characters, cluster-ssh

I am using `cssh` (cluster-ssh) to ssh to multiple machines simultaneously. Everything works great, except that `cssh` intercepts <kbd>F10</kbd> key  (which in cssh opens menu.

This is very unfortunate, because I am using <kbd>F10</kbd> a lot, for example to close midnight commander.

Is there a way to configure `cssh` so that it ignores <kbd>F10</kbd> and lets it through ?

I am using LXDE/Openbox on Debian Wheezy

**UPDATE**: in the past, I had similar problem with `terminator` terminal emulator eating <kbd>F10</kbd> when using `midnight commander`. This problem was resolved by adding the following to my `/usr/share/themes/Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

```
binding "NoKeyboardNavigation" {
    unbind "<shift>F10"
}

class "*" binding "NoKeyboardNavigation"
```

This however has no effect on `cssh`. Therefore I suspect, this is not caused by the window manager, but rather by `cssh` itself.

Comment: Try pressing `ESC` `0` instead of `F10`, that may work.

Comment: @Martin von Wittich - thanks, Esc+0 works. But it is impractical, because I am so used to F10.

Comment: @Christopher - `ps` is showing `/usr/bin/xterm` in the process list. So I guess yes.

Comment: @Christopher - BTW, as a side note: does it mean `cssh` can use other terminal emulators than xterm? Would it be possible to tell `cssh` to open the terminals in `terminator`, for instance ?

Comment: @Christopher  - thanks a lot. I am getting some errors, however. But since this is a diferent issue, I have created a new [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206263/cssh-change-terminal-from-xterm-to-terminator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior isn't actually part of cssh, but rather the widget toolkit it's using, [Tk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)), which is why it doesn't show up in the list of configurable hotkeys and setting `use_hotkeys` to `no` doesn't disable it. I couldn't find a non-programmatic way to fix it, but if you're building cssh yourself ([not hard](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh/blob/master/README)) you can make a small change to the code to rebind <kbd>F10</kbd> so it does nothing. Add the following line to `lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm` in the `create_menubar()` function:

```
$windows{main_window}->bind("all", "<Key-F10>" => sub {});
```

---

Patch:

```
diff --git a/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm b/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm
index cc71507..de4706e 100644
--- a/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm
+++ b/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm
@@ -1737,6 +1737,7 @@ sub create_menubar() {
     my ($self) = @_;
     $self->debug( 2, "create_menubar: started" );
     $menus{bar} = $windows{main_window}->Menu();
+    $windows{main_window}->bind("all", "<Key-F10>" => sub {});
     $windows{main_window}->configure( -menu => $menus{bar}, );

     $menus{file} = $menus{bar}->cascade(
```

Comment: @Michael Mrozek - this is great. Works perfectly. Thanks.