# cssh: change terminal from xterm to terminator

Tags: terminal, xterm, gnome-terminator, cluster-ssh

I would like `cssh` to use `terminator` terminal emulator, instead of the default `xterm`. In `~/.clusterssh/config` I have changed the following line:

```
#terminal=/usr/bin/xterm
terminal=/usr/bin/terminator
```

But when I start `cssh` I get following error:

```
Opening to: server1 server2
Usage: terminator [options]

terminator: error: no such option: -g
Usage: terminator [options]

terminator: error: no such option: -g
Cannot open pipe for reading when talking to server1 : Interrupted system call
```

Apparently, `cssh` is passing some parameters to `xterm`, which `terminator` does not recognize.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: You can find out what parameters are being passed by changing your terminal to `echo` and starting `cssh` from a command line in a terminal; the parameters will then be printed out in that same terminal.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you may not get this to work as I doubt that Terminator will accept synthetic events and I don't think that multiple terminal per window model is compatible, but If you want to try the best source is the README.Debian.gz from the debian package. I have included the relevant portion below, but It would probably be much simpler to just use Terminator's grouping option

> Super+g: Group all terminals so that any input sent to one of them, goes to all of them. [(from the man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator%20terminator(1))

---

> *TERMINAL EMULATORS*
>
> Clusterssh no longer allows the use of just any Debian terminal
>   emulator  that provides x-terminal-emulator, since a number of them
>   don't support the XSendEvents resource.  By default, clusterssh will
>   invoke xterm.  To  change this, create or modify your config file to
>   contain the line:
>
> ```
>     terminal = /path/to/my/favorite/terminal-emulator
> ```
>
> Note that this terminal emulator must accept the "-xrm" command line 
>   switch to set XTerm.VT100.allowSendEvents:true (or something that does
>   the same thing).  If your terminal emulator provides equivalent
>   functionality with a different switch, or provides it implicitly, you
>   can set this with the parameter "terminal_allow_send_events" in  the
>   config file.
>
> If you are having trouble getting clusterssh to work with uxterm, you
>   should either delete the "terminal_allow_send_events" option  from
>   your config file, or update the value to:
>
> ```
>   UXTerm.VT100.allowSendEvents:true
> ```
>
> or simply:
>
> ```
>   *.VT100.allowSendEvents:true
> ```
>
> Older versions of clusterssh would create the .csshrc file with the
>   class set to "XTerm" which prevents the uxterm from receiving events.
>
> The terminal emulator must also accept:
>
> ```
>     -e <command>
>     -font <font>
>      System-wide configure changes can be made by editing /etc/csshrc.
> ```
>
> Debian terminal emulator packages tested and known NOT to work with
>   clusterssh:
>
> ---
>
> (please send updates either directly to the maintainer or via the bug
>   tracking system)
>
> gnome-terminal konsole kterm xvt xfce4-terminal mlterm
>
> Debian terminal emulator packages tested and believed to work:
>
> ---
>
> xterm rxvt rxvt-beta aterm (only with "terminal_allow_send_events ="
>   in ~/.clusterssh/config) wterm (only with "terminal_allow_send_events
>   =" in ~/.clusterssh/config) pterm (although it requires input focus before any output is displayed) eterm (although it doesn't use the
>   -font switch)
>
> Note that xterm-wrappers like lxterm and uxterm that immediately
>   background themselves will NOT work.
>
> If you use a script to spawn your terminals, make sure that it takes
>   takes $* as an argument, and that it doesn't background itself.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `terminator` does not accept `cssh`s (default or hard-wired) parameters.  Instead of trying to change these, how about creating a wrapper for the terminator startup:

```
cat > /usr/bin/start_terminator.sh
#!/bin/bash
# debug info: dump parameters
echo "start_terminator.sh called with paremeters: ${@}" > /tmp/start_terminator.sh.cmdline
# now start terminator avoiding invalid parameters given by cssh
exec /usr/bin/terminator
^D
```

(^D is Ctrl+D to end the keyboard input and `cat` command), then

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/start_terminator.sh
```

and replace the `terminal=/usr/bin/terminator` by `terminal=/usr/bin/start_terminator.sh` in your `~/.clusterssh/config`.  If terminator does not start after this change then please look at our debug output at `/tmp/start_terminator.sh.cmdline` to see whether some of the parameters need to be passed to `/usr/bin/terminator` when `exec`ing it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`manual for cssh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cssh) it has this to say:

> --tile,-g|--no-tile,-G
>     Enable|Disable window tiling (overriding the config file)

With that said, I would propose disabling the `window tiling` option then review the [`manual for terminator`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator) which has this to say regarding window tiling:

> --geometry=GEOMETRY
>     Specifies the preferred size and position of Terminator's window; see x(7).

It seems that some general configuration options are going to be needed to switch terminals for `cssh`.

Comment: Thanks, but what concrete parameters do I need to change in `~/.clusterssh/config`? Using option `-G` on the commandline, i.e. `cssh -G server1 server2` produces the same error. The option `-G` does not make any difference.

Comment: I should have been more specific; `cssh` needs to pass `--geometry` to `terminator` or disable the feature entirely.

Comment: so basically, your advice is, I should read the manual to figure out the answer to my question.

Comment: Nope, just that the `cssh` tool seems to be equipped with configurable options that should address the problem you're experiencing and you didn't make any mention of them in your original question.